# importing a outlook.pst file into thunderbird

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, import, pst

trying to import my outlook.pst into thunderbird, but it seems my computer has to have outlook running on the computer to do this import.

I have the outlook.pst file, can't I just point thunderbird to that file somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Thunderbird PST Import plugin](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Communications/Email/Thunderbird-PST-Import-plugin-33014.shtml) :

> Thunderbird PST Import plugin was
>   created to allow importing Outlook PST
>   and select which email folder to
>   import. Thunderbird PST Import plugin
>   is licensed under GPL (uses libpst).

Some more information is here : [Import .pst files](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_.pst_files).
Unfortunately, some part of the described proceeding requires Outlook to be installed (you may even install an evaluation version and uninstall it afterward).

Comment: The libpst module doesn't seem to have a good reputation. However, the "Import .pst files" link you point to has some good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. They both use different file formats.

Also, I think you need Outlook to convert .pst files to a different format.

Answer (score 0):

simply go to tools > import> select outlook and import whatever you want.

just install outlook import your .pst data file there and then do the above.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Thunderbird was unable to handle importing from multiple `.pst` files. I had to move all my mails back manually into the "base" `.pst` file and then remove the others using file/data file management.  Then I made sure that the antivirus was off and that Outlook was running and set as the default mail program while I did it.