# How to import outlook emails into Thunderbird, both on different systems?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, import

I have folder(`Outlook Express`) of emails from outlook of other system.

I need to import these emails to my system in `Thunderbird`. My system doesn't have Outlook.

I only have copied folder of outlook in my system.

How to import these emails to Thunderbird?

Comment: @Shakehar That question talks about going from Thunderbird → Outlook, not the other way round.

Comment: I guess I copied the wrong link,here is the actual one:http://superuser.com/questions/46230/importing-a-outlook-pst-file-into-thunderbird?rq=1